# Additional parameter to pass to J query token input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing, jquery-tokeninput

I am using jquery token input for search purpose in a texbox in my MVC pjct as
below

```
(".diag").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis","Preapproval")",
{
      theme: 'facebook',
      preventDuplicates: true,
      searchingText: 'Searching diagnosis code...',
      tokenLimit: 1,
      hintText: 'Diagnosis Code'
});
```

by default the query parameter 'q' will be passed and return the desired result.

this text is under a table. In the same row there is a dropdownlist.
Now my requirement is while searching happens in jquery token input i need to pass the selected value of the dropdownlist also. Is it possible?

Edited

```
var qq;

 $("#service").on('change', '.act_type', function () {  
 {
qq = $(this).val();
});



$("#service").find(".act_code").last().tokenInput("../Preapproval/SearchDiagnosis?queryParam=q" + "&type="+qq,
                {
                    theme: 'facebook',
                    preventDuplicates: true,
                    searchingText: 'Searching...',
                    tokenLimit: 1,
                    hintText: 'Activity code'
                });
```

the table row is creating dynamically and assigning tokeninput the class.

```
public JsonResult SearchDiagnosis(string q, string type)
        {...
}
```

**I changed the code like this**

```
$("#service").on('change', '.act_type', function () {  //$(".diag").change(function () {
qq = $(this).val();
var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
$("#code-"+id[1]).tokenInput("../Preapproval/Searchactivitycode?queryParam=q" + "&type=" + qq,
               {
                   theme: 'facebook',
                   preventDuplicates: true,
                   searchingText: 'Searching...',
                   tokenLimit: 1,
                   hintText: 'Activity code'
               });
```

Now it pass the correct value assigned to qq. But now iam facing another issue. if the dropdown in the same row is changed more than one time that much number of texbox will be created with tokeninput because he tokeninput is assigning at the change event. Is there any solution to stop this?

**Edited**

I searched a lot for assigning this to a dynamic created row didn't got any. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try something simple like below

```
 $(".diag").tokenInput("/SearchDiagnosis/Preapproval?queryParam=q" + "&type=qq",
                    { tokenLimit: 1, });
```

Comment: Hi Anto, thanks for the reply, but how qq will take the selected value of dropdown

Comment: @Sachu get the value in var and assign like below var qq= $('#dropDownId').val()

Comment: @ Anto, I assigned value of dropdown to var qq on it change event and it is assigning correctly but when calling the token input the value passing to parameter type is string "qq" not the value stored in qq

Comment: @Sachu for that you have to slighlty modify the above code use this $(".diag").tokenInput("/SearchDiagnosis/Preapproval?queryParam=q" + "&type="+qq,
                    { tokenLimit: 1, });

Comment: i already tried that. That time the value passed to type is giving as "undefined"

Comment: CAn you update the question with your new code then we can check whats wrong @Sachu

Comment: var qq;
$("#ddlcheck").change(function(){
    qq= $('#ddlcheck').val()
 alert(qq)})   instead of your code try use this method to assign value to qq

Comment: The rows of the table is dynamic so the names will have unique number generated dynamically so the above code can't be used.

Comment: .sorry to disturb you. I changed the code as edited above it is taking the value of qq now but facing another issue mentioned. any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75906/discussion-between-anto-king-and-sachu).

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by `onSend` callback of the plugin

[jquery tokeninput filter query send extra parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950973/jquery-tokeninput-filter-query-send-extra-parameters/31720287#31720287)