# How to pass selected value as extra parameter to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-tokeninput

my coding part

```
$("#demo-input").tokenInput("data/autosuggest-search-city.php", 
        {
            searchDelay: 2000,
            minChars: 3,
            tokenLimit: 10
        });
```

I want to send the selected values as extra parameter to "data/autosuggest-search-city.php".

For example, 
Initially I search and select one value from list
then again searching, this time I want to send the 1st selected value to server.

How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery tokeninput filter query send extra parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950973/jquery-tokeninput-filter-query-send-extra-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TokenInput* plugin doesn't support that natively.
You can however make a simple workaround to update *"AJAX url"* whenever a token is added or removed from selection.

Use `onAdd` and `onDelete` [callbacks](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/#callbacks) to trigger *"AJAX url"* changes;
Get selected tokens using `selector.tokenInput("get")` [method](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/#methods);
Set the new *"AJAX url"* by updating `.data("settings").url` of the element;

```
// cache the original url:
var token_url = "data/autosuggest-search-city.php";

$("#demo-input").tokenInput(token_url, {
    searchDelay : 2000,
    minChars    : 3,
    tokenLimit  : 10,
    onAdd       : function(){
        urlChange.call(this);
    },
    onDelete    : function(){
        urlChange.call(this);
    }
});

function urlChange(){
    var tokens = '', token_list = $(this).tokenInput("get");
    // proceed if any token/s are selected:
    if(token_list.length){
        // loop through the selected tokens (if more than one is selected)
        $.each(token_list, function(i, token){
            // use token "id" (or "name" if you wish) and separate them with comma:
            tokens += token.id + ',';
        });
        // update url:
        $(this).data("settings").url = token_url + '?selected_tokens='+tokens.replace(/,+$/,'');
    }else{
        // leave original url if no tokens are selected:
        $(this).data("settings").url = token_url;
    }
};
```

Comment: showing error in console "TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined"

Comment: @ranjith , I'm not really sure why it doesn't work for you... Works pretty nice for me http://phillip.com.pl/pub/tokeninput/

Comment: It works after update lib file(jquery.tokeninput.js) v: 1.6.0.