# How do I modify the jquery-token-Input css file to create to get a much bigger text area and tokens like described below?

Tags: css, jquery-tokeninput

I am using jqueryInputToken and acts-as-taggable-on gem. I was able to make the back-end work. However, as part of using the jqueryTokenInput plugin, my text_area  became so slim and looks more like a tiny text_field. 
Here is a picture of what my text_area looks like as a result of the jQueryInput plugin without hovering:
[image]

And when you hover the "X" sign to delete the tag apears like in the picture below:

[image]

I want to modify the css so that the text_area becomes big and the token looks exactly like below:

[image]

How should I modify the css below to reach my desired look for the text_field and tokens ?

Here is the css:

```
/* Example tokeninput style #2: Mac Style */
fieldset.token-input-mac {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #A4BDEC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset.token-input-mac.token-input-dropdown-mac {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

ul.token-input-list-mac {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-height: 1px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

ul.token-input-list-mac.error {
  border: 1px solid #C52020;
}

ul.token-input-list-mac li {
list-style-type: none;
}

li.token-input-token-mac p {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.token-input-token-mac span {
    color: #231C34;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* TOKENS */

li.token-input-token-mac {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height: 12pt;
    margin: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background: none;
    background-color: #0F004E;
    color: #fefefe;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-highlighted-token-mac {
    background-color: #231C34;
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-selected-token-mac {
    background-color: #231C34;
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

li.token-input-highlighted-token-mac span.token-input-delete-token-mac {
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-selected-token-mac span.token-input-delete-token-mac {
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-input-token-mac {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.token-input-input-token-mac input {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: none;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac p {
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac h3.token-input-dropdown-category-mac {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-dropdown-item-mac span.token-input-dropdown-item-description-mac {
    float: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd {
    background: #0F004E;
    color: #bb8322; //Official Red
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac:hover,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd:hover,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac:focus,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd:focus {
    color: #fff;
 }

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac span.token-input-dropdown-item-description-mac,
 div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd span.token-input-dropdown-item-description-mac {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do something like this and have at least a rough version of something working, so I'll put this here in case it's useful.  I used the Facebook theme - it looks like you used a different theme.  I mention that because this influences things like class names in my answer.  Also I think that Facebook might be more of what you're after (see the cosmetic stuff below).

I'll split this into two parts: a structural part first, and then a cosmetic part.

### Structure

Part of my problem was due to the fact that the token input code replaces your HTML with some of its own.  I wrote this HTML

```html
<div id="searchBar">
<input type="text" id="bigTextInput" />
</div>
```

and the combination of the insert-token-input-here call:

```
$("#bigTextInput").tokenInput(token_url, {
    theme: 'facebook',...
```

and the user entering a couple of things, made it look like this (with my comments):

```html
<div id="searchBar">
    <ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
      <li class="token-input-token-facebook"> <!-- one of these per user input -->
        <p>first thing the user entered
          <span class="token-input-delete-token-facebook">X</span></p></li>
      <li class="token-input-token-facebook">
        <p>second thing the user entered
          <span class="token-input-delete-token-facebook">X</span></p></li>
      <li class="token-input-input-token-facebook"> <!-- 1 on the end for entering the next selection -->
        <input id="token-input-Y"> <!-- Y = whatever Id you gave to the original input (bigTextInput in my case) -->
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input id=Y display:none /> <!-- the thing you created, but then is hidden and replaced by the ul etc. -->
</div>
```

The `input` I created has been hidden away, and in its place there's now a `ul`, with an `li` per thing the user entered and an extra `li` for the user to add more things.

To change the height successfully I had to set the height I wanted on the `ul`:

```
$("ul.token-input-list-facebook").height(newHeight + "px");
```

### Bonus structure stuff - auto-resizing

I started with just a large box, but this didn't look good if the user had entered only a small amount of stuff.  So I thought I'd try to make it start small (a single line high) and then grow on demand.

To do this I made sure that the `ul` wouldn't create scrollbars:

```css
ul.token-input-list-facebook {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

and then if the content overflowed, I would re-size things.  I checked for overflow by adding a handler to the add and delete events of the token input:

```js
$("#bigTextInput").tokenInput(token_url, {
    theme: 'facebook',
    onAdd: function(){
                growSearchBoxSizes();
           },
    onDelete: function(){
                shrinkSearchBoxSizes();
              }
});
```

The best way I found to detect overflow in `growSearchBoxSizes` was to compare the `offsetHeight` and `scrollHeight` properties of the enclosing div:

```js
var heightA = parseFloat($("#searchBar")[0].offsetHeight);
var heightB = parseFloat($("#searchBar")[0].scrollHeight);
```

I suggest you write these to console.log, experiment with what they show when the input does and doesn't overflow, and have code to add 1 line's height when they show you that there is overflow.

I couldn't come up with a good way to detect when it was time to shrink (e.g. after the user had deleted a line's worth of stuff), so in the delete handler I shrink the box down to its starting size and then grow it back up to whatever height is needed, i.e. until there is no overflow.  (A hack, but it seems to work.)

Actually, I was already using a handler for the add and delete events because of [wanting to prevent what the user had already entered from showing up in the auto-completion list for later inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938988/how-to-pass-selected-value-as-extra-parameter-to-ajax-call), which you might want to also consider.

### Cosmetic

The reason why I suggested that you might want to switch to the Facebook theme is that it has the X present all the time as you want.  The colours and shapes aren't as you want them, but I hope that this should be a matter of just defining overrides in your CSS as appropriate.